# Chosen css for normal textbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I really like the chosen jquery plugin for select boxes, but is it possible to style normal textboxes with the styles defined in the chosen.css file or do i have to change the chosen.css to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its an old question, but i have just done the same.

I accomplished this by adding a new css entry for all inputs.

```
input {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eeeeee', GradientType=0 );   
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(52%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #f4f4f4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%); 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius   : 5px;
  border-radius        : 5px;
  -moz-background-clip   : padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip        : padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ffffff inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow   : 0 0 3px #ffffff inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow        : 0 0 3px #ffffff inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just use firebug/ similar inspector to inspect their `CSS` and apply those class for you `textbox`.

Alternatively, you can also take their `CSS` properties by inspecting and apply them with you own `id/class` combinations.