# input looks like chosen select

Tags: html, css, input, jquery-chosen

Is it possible to make input looks like chosen (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) selects?
I don't need autocomplete, I need round borders, blue border on active, same height, same background.

PS: standart inputs and chosen selects look too diffent.

Comment: [Chosen css for normal textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931201/chosen-css-for-normal-textbox?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate  [Chosen css for normal textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931201/chosen-css-for-normal-textbox)

Comment: @Ghommey unfortunately I can't select your answer as accepted answer

Comment: @pinouchon yep it is dub

Comment: @Andrew You have to wait a little while before you can, you should be able to now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

[Form elements examples here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms). They look more or less like chosen inputs.